# Tag a comment as the correct answer

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer

I ask a question in this forum: [Bug report invalid, unupdated packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118293/bug-report-invalid-unupdated-packages)
And I want to tag as a valid answer the comment of a comment. Is it possible?
The comment is not the answer that I search...but yes the comment of the comment.
How I have to proceed in this case?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I would ask the user to consider adding an answer. That way, he or she deserves the credit for the answer. If after a while they do not, answer the question yourself and after the time limit lifts, go ahead and accept your own answer. That way it can be answered for the rest of the community...I'm not too sure you get reputation for it though.

Comment: @RyanMcClure Speaking of answers as comments, I'd consider adding that as your own answer below. :)

Comment: :P Duh. Can't take my own advice....thanks Warrioring!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ask the user to consider adding an answer. That way, he or she deserves the credit for the answer. If after a while they do not, answer the question yourself and after the time limit lifts, go ahead and accept your own answer. That way it can be answered for the rest of the community...I'm not too sure you get reputation for it though.

Comment: You *can* get rep from an answer to your own question - if people vote for it.  You do not get the "someone accepted your answer" rep, however.